# Using GAWK to sum certain numbers line by line

Tags: gawk, numeric-data

My lines will look as such

```
X 2.63766751981802 Y 1.68326762144808 Z 0 XX 2.63577810877244 YY 1.67475013544567 ZZ 0
```

Using GNU `awk`, how do I print `(X-XX) + (Y-YY)` on the end of every line? 
Just to complicate things I need the `()` numbers to always be converted to plain numbers ie strip the negatives.
Looking to "mark" lines that the ending sum is greater than say 1.

Comment: 1) format your description; 2) post the expected final result

Comment: What are `() numbers`?

Comment: Ideally ouput would be-

Comment: Ideally ouput would be-" X 2.63766751981802 Y 1.68326762144808 Z 0 XX 2.63577810877244 YY 1.67475013544567 ZZ 0 Q 0.010406897 Q being (2.63766751981802-2.63577810877244) + (1.68326762144808-1.67475013544567)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{ print $0, "("$2"-"$8") + ("$4"-"$10")"}' inputfile
X 2.63766751981802 Y 1.68326762144808 Z 0 XX 2.63577810877244 YY 1.67475013544567 ZZ 0 (2.63766751981802-2.63577810877244) + (1.68326762144808-1.67475013544567)
```